# RX: Best approach to async download a list of something from a WCF-service?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, system.reactive

The result Im after is a list (WPF) of items that is populated one at a time async from a web service (WCF). I figured RX could be a good option for this?

My web service method is returning an array of strings (for now) and at the client-side Im using:

```
var list = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string[]>(client.BeginList, client.EndList);
```

But now what? Im not familiar with RX at all and I feel very lost. Anyhow I guess my web service has to stream the list instead of sending it in a chunk if I want them to pop in continously?

Answer (score 1):

`FromObservablePattern` returns a `Func<IObservable>` (or possibly with arguments if the service takes any), so you call the delegate and then subscribe to the source:

```
var list = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string[]>(client.BeginList, client.EndList);

list().Subscribe(items =>
{
    // items is the string[]
});
```