# WCF + RX send list of objects to front-end as batch

Tags: c#, wcf, system.reactive

I have a requirement to fetch pretty big list (Quotes for several years of a symbol) from a WCF service and show it in a chart control. Idea is to batch send quotes and in the client keep receiving it asynchronously. I am looking for a good example on how to achieve this preferably using Rx. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491137/rx-best-approach-to-async-download-a-list-of-something-from-a-wcf-service) is the closest I have come accross. Can someone please point to a good reference (or provide sample code) with both client and server side example?

Comment: I think the question is too broad. There are a lot of possible answers, which can be limited by providing more details and/or specifying the scope.

Comment: Please add more detail.  What your service API looks like, for example.  With that, people will be able to show how to use Rx to retrieve the batch data from it.